# Quaternion angle calculation

Tags: quaternions, angle

I'm working on a programming project, in this project I'm receiving an angle as a quaternion value, I partially understand how they work but I don't find any math to get the values I need.
What I would need is the angle between a fictional line/vector going to the the quaternion point from the origin (yes I know what you are thinking, but I couldn't think of a better explanation) and the "earth" a plane that is perpendicular to the gravitational vector, in this case one of your planes of reference.
Also I would need to get the rotation of the line/vector, this time the rotation should be according to the plane perpendicular to itself.
If possible all angles should be described as an angle between -180° and 180° (that's were my troubles are from.

If someone could help me by this it would be awesome
Thank you in advanced
~TJ

In this picture γ complementary angle of the first questing and R is the secondary angle.
[Angles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jztA.png)

Comment: Do you mean something like [Conversion between quaternions and Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles)?

Comment: I actualy tried implementing that a few times but it did't give me a result between -180° and 180°, I alsways had -90° to 90°. These are the formulas I used.

Comment: gx = 2 * (xz - wy) || gy = 2 * (wx + yz) || gz = ww - xx - yy + zz || yaw = atan2(2*xy - 2*wz, 2*ww + 2*xx - 1) || pitch = atan(gx / sqrt(gygy + gzgz)) || float roll = atan(gy/gz)

Comment: You should **always** use [atan2(y,x)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) instead of atan(y/x). It is a common mistake.

Comment: That did it. Thank you Somos.

Answer (score 0):

> You should **always** use atan2(y,x) instead of atan(y/x). It is a common mistake. – @Somos

Thank you, apparently that did it!